# WPF how to load an XML file on a specific interval

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a WPF application for a kyosk.

App loads XML content every hour from a remote Server.

I need to call the Server every hour (I do not need absolute precision) and update the app (Download Data in Background an update Objects bound to UI).

What is the easier way to do in wihtinthe WPF application. Please provide a sample of code if possible.

Comment: Start with some [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Alberto, you seem to have the right idea... would you care to add an answer and provide the question author with some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways to create a periodic refresh.  Here's a snippet containing a simple thread loop...

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool _isActive;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartXmlRefresher(5000);
        }
        private void StartXmlRefresher(int sleepMilliseconds)
        {
            _isActive = true;
            Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (_isActive)
                    {
                        RefreshXml();
                        if(_isActive) Thread.Sleep(sleepMilliseconds);
                    }
                });
        }
        private void RefreshXml()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Refresh started");
            // your stuff here
            Console.WriteLine(@"Refresh completed");
        }
    }
```

The thread loops until the _isActive member is set to false.  After each refresh, the thread will sleep for the designated amount of time.  You can also use any of the Timer variants to do the same thing.

NOTE:  this snippet is for .net 4.5.  IF you are using a less senior release, you'll need to use the task factory to start the thread.  Here's a snippet showing how to use the factory to start a thread...

```
private void StartXmlRefresherWithFactory(int sleepMilliseconds)
{
    _isActive = true;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (_isActive)
        {
            RefreshXml();
            Thread.Sleep(sleepMilliseconds);
        }
    });
}
```

Calling StartNew is functionally equivalent to creating a task using one of its constructors and then calling Start to schedule it for execution. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.100).aspx

The 4.5 Task.Run method is essentially syntactic sugar for the factory method, so whichever you use will give the same result.

Sorry for the formatting; it appears not to be working today.

Comment: could you post an example using task factory? thanks

Comment: @GibboK, I amended the answer to include both methods, plus a link to the MSDN dox.  It looks like the formatter is amok again though